# Softlayer API website is not available?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Can I ask your question?

I searched sldn.softlayer.com in order to find softlayer api.
But this website was temporary unavailable.

Will the site be integrated into bluemix? Or is it a temporary technical issue?

Thanks.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it will be integrated to Bluemix. It may be temporary technical issue, because I'm still seeing this right now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I check the site but now only connect Softlayer API Examples.

Answer (score 0):

The SoftLayer API information seems to be available at the following URL: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/overview